# $(z+i)^n + (\overline{z+i})^n = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve an equation:

$$(z+i)^n + (\overline{z+i})^n = 0$$

where $\overline{z}$ corresponds to conjugation of complex number $z$.

**My work so far**

I was trying to somehow expand conjugation of $(z+i)^n$. I tried to use fact that $(\overline{z+i})^n = \overline{(z+i)}^n$ and to denote $(z+i)^n = t$ to obtain equation:

$$t + \overline t = 0$$

But I'm not sure how to solve this equation. I tried to multiply this equation by $t$ and by $\overline{t}$ but it doesn't seem to be a good idea. Could you please give me a hand with solving this equation?

Comment: Hint : Since $t +  \bar{t} =0 $, maybe think about which complex numbers $t$ satisfies $\bar{t} = -t$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $t +  \bar{t} =0 $, we can think about which complex numbers $t$ satisfies $\bar{t} = -t$. These are the imaginary numbers. So, $$(z+i)^n = i b ; \hspace{2mm} b \in \Bbb{R}$$
and thus, assuming $b>0$,
$$z+i = w_n b^{1/n}$$
where, $w_n$ are the $n$th roots of $i$.

If $b<0$, we will have $$z+i = \omega_n (-b)^{1/n}$$ instead, where $\omega_n$ are the $n$th roots of $-i$.